# Android ContentResolver.setsyncautomatically not working across multiple devices for me

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an android app, in which i syc my data with Google cloud which works fine for me, the problem I'm facing is that, i have the app installed on more than 1 device and have logged in with the same account. Now when ever i insert new data or update the data from device 1 that gets uploaded to Google. But device 2 with same account is not getting synced automatically, if i do a manually syn then i can see all the changes that are made in device 1.

Following is the code that i used

```
    Account account = new Account("abcd@gmail.com", "com.google");
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, "com.example.synData.Test", 1);
    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, "com.example.synData.Test", true);
    ContentResolver.requestSync(account, "com.example.synData.Test", extras);
```

Please someone help on this.

Thanks a lot for your valuable time

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked on the documentation regarding Completion Events? These notifications are sent to your app even when it is not running, so you could force an update when this event is triggered. More information is available on this link: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/completion